# CatalogSearch - add weight to different attributes

Tags: magento-1.7, catalogsearch, fulltext

I have my fulltext catalogsearch working fine for now, but I still see some not-so-relevant results. Before telling me that Magento's built-in search is terrible I'll tell you that I know there are free extensions out there etc etc, but I don't want to cripple my site with any more extensions.

What's happening is that the "relevance" (which is the score) only gets to 2.0 (from 0), and thus I have say 10 products with the same 2.0 relevance, while I should only have about 3.

**My question is** : is there a way in which I could tell Magento to add a better score for say `name` than `sku`(programmatically or not)?
A bit like Prestashop handles it (see picture below)

[image: Prestashop's score system]

Thanks for your insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're willing to convert to Lucene Search which is actually built into the Zend framework that Magento partially uses and only needs a module to activate, you can have relevance and weighting.

By adding a supplemental search attribute, you can even have variants, nicknames and jargon without polluting your product description.

[image]

One such module is Blast Lucene and the weighting and ability to select a range of attributes to add to the pool made this non-free module pay for itself in about two months as customers could actually find stuff.

The short answer is "there's no free way you can improve Magento search". I wasted a lot of time, got complaints from both customers and management till I got out of that mindset. Fulltext might allow for the relevance to work, but it's not as competent as Lucene.

It's pretty embarrassing that Magento didn't use Lucene in the first place...

Comment: pretty embarrassing indeed, I've never tried EE but I hope a better search engine is buitl-in. Thanks for your insight though. Could you please provide a link to this extension to complete your answer, I might want to take a look at this module if a customer asks for it.

Comment: [PHP4U Blast Lucene Search for Magento](http://php4u.co.uk/blast-search-lucene-magento-extension/)

Answer (score 0):

Short answer - no, there is no build in options, but there are modules at the magento connect that add it.

What they do is create own full_text index, with the score calculated as attributes with weights.

Also there are Solr integrations.

If you want to edit the query, you can start from app\code\core\Mage\CatalogSearch\Model\Resource\Fulltext.php,  method `prepareResult`

Comment: I understand you, but as I said, I don't want to add any other extensions to my site.

Comment: Can you please clarify what kind of answer you expect form the community? I can't get the idea really.  So if you thought there is something in the config, the answer is NO.  Would you like some pointers were to start with the code modifications?

Comment: aye, hence my edit ^^ I know there is nothing from the base Magento that would allow me to do it. But as far as code is concerned, I have no idea where to look for, the CatalogSearch "module" being that big. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I've also edited the answer.

Comment: I see what you mean, but I think I need to find the place where Magento actually write "2.0" in the `relevance` column.

Comment: _I understand you, but as I said_ - Well, I have programming experience, I wasted a lot of time trying that route, it was a total waste of time. There's nothing in Magento's current search "Thingy" (calling it an engine would be slander) to build on to really improve it much.